# Latex: show my APA format Jornal publication in my resume

Tags: biblatex

I using Latex to made my Resume. 
I want to show my APA format Jornal publication in my resume.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create the list the sources, try this code:

```
documentclass{article}

% remove the numbers of the sources
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    % output the list
    \begin{thebibliography}{}
        \bibitem{litlink1}  author#1. "title #1"
        \bibitem{litlink2}  author#2. "title #2"
        \bibitem{other-link-name}  author#3. "title #3"
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!